# Get refresh token and gmail user profile in node.js using OAuth2

Tags: node.js, google-api, oauth-2.0

I would like to authorize the gmail login in my app using simple-oauth2 in node.js and also trying to get the user profile  ,initially Im doing the authentication ,the code is

```
    var oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2')({
    clientID: configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    site: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/',
    tokenPath: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    authorizationPath: 'oauth2/auth'
});
```

// Authorization uri definition

```
var authorization_uri = oauth2.authCode.authorizeURL({
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    state: '382332$'
});
app.get('/auth/google', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(authorization_uri);
});
```

Callback is,

```
    app.get('/auth/google/callback', function (req, res) {
    var code = req.query.code;
     oauth2.authCode.getToken({
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback'
    }, saveToken);

    function saveToken(error, result, profile1) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Access Token Error', error);
        }
        token = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);
        console.log('token',token)
    }
```

The result of token is like this :

```
{ access_token: 'ya29.lQKN8a2ECM0h5ECWL4NcThS924m_eMUWg9I3BVfRvkTiK-lt-     8_1bCLjBmtmi68Kg8k',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expires_in: 3599,
  id_token: 'somelongstring',
  expires_at: Sat Feb 27 2016 16:38:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 
  }
```

In the token response I couldn't get the refresh token . Is there any other method to get refresh token ?

And also how to get the logged in user's profile detail once the login is success.Please suggest some solution ..! 
    Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with simple-oauth2 but I know with passport-google (http://passportjs.org/docs/google) it does what you require out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

I added these

```
approval_prompt: 'force',
access_type: 'offline',
```

in the authorization_uri like,

```
var authorization_uri = oauth2.authCode.authorizeURL({
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback',
    approval_prompt: 'force',
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile     
    state: '3832$'
});
```

This worked for me !!